# Explicit FTP over TLS fails : Warning: ftp_fput(): data_accept: SSL/TLS handshake failed

Tags: php, ssl, ftp, openssl

I'm trying to connect to a FTP server which requires Explicit FTP over TLS, All FTP clients work fine, but i can't get it to work in PHP:

```
<?php
$ftp = ftp_ssl_connect($host, 21);
$login = ftp_login($ftp, $user, $pass);
ftp_pasv($ftp, true);

$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fwrite($fp, 'Salam');
rewind($fp);
ftp_fput($ftp, '/file.txt', $fp);
```

The server is configured correctly and it has no problem with clients like filezilla, lftp, [ftptest.net](https://ftptest.net)

PHP version: 7.4.3

OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.1.1f 31 Mar 2020

Comment: Yes i saw this answer but it says since PHP `5.6.26` the re-use TLS session is added but i'm using PHP 7.4

Comment: Also tested on PHP 7.2, 7.3

Comment: Reproduced in PHP 7.4.30; as said by Amin definitely not linked with PHP version here, but caused by blocked transfer ports, see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After A couple of days of trying i figured out that the FTP server is using port `21` but a different port range for data transfer, that explains why, connection and login works , but listing and upload/download doesn't. and those ports were blocked in firewall.

I asked the Hosting provider to allow outgoing connection on those ports, the problem solved.